# How To Query Item Using InstantObject Query

Tags: delphi, instantobjects

I'm Using InstantObjects. I Have 2 classes TSalesOrder And TSalesOrderItem. TSalesOrderItem is member of collection in TSalesOrder. I'm having trouble to query Tsalesorderitem data to be displayed in fastreport. Does anyone have solution for this?

Comment: you're having trouble, this means you got an error or you don't know how to do it? provide some simple code to explain what you're facing on.

Comment: No , I don't get error. I Want to query data from Tsalesorderitem, but I can't do it. Now, i have to retrieve data from Tsalesorderitem manually. I must query "select * from tsalesorder" then i do looping in  tsalesorder.

Comment: Yes, I got the answer. We can load Items of Tsalesorder using its container name

Comment: @bagus prasojo: You can migrate your comment as answer and accept it.